# How to modify a value at an address

Tags: c, pointers

This is a pretty basic question regarding pointers and dereferencing in C but here goes. I have the following:

```
char    str2[]  = "Word2";

printf("String2: %s | Location: %p\n", str2, str2);
unsigned long add_str2 = (long) &str2;
printf("Address of str2 starts at: 0x%lx\n", add_str2);
```

After this, I can confirm that `add_str2` has the correct memory address:

> ```
> String2: Word2 | Location: 0x7ffc623b8102 
> Address of str2 starts at: 0x7ffc623b8102
> ```

Using `add_str2` how would I modify the `W` into an `L`. What I tried was:

```
* add_str2 = 'L';
```

> 0_main.c:46:5: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘long unsigned int’)

What would be the correct way to do this? And is there a way to modify the value at a memory address without a pointer type, or does it require either an explicit pointer or one that is cast, such as `* (char *) add_str2 = 'L';` ?

Comment: It must be a pointer. You can't dereference anything that is not a pointer.

Comment: @kaylum I see. So given a memory address as a number, in order to modify that if it's modifiable I have to do: `* (type *) addr = value;` ?

Comment: No, casting is unnecessary. Just declare add_str2 as a char* pointer: `char* add_str2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify a value at a memory address you need a pointer in C.

`unsigned long add_str2` is not a pointer, so you cannot use it as such.

Casting a number to a pointer is a mine field, as several systems use different sizes for different integers and pointers. For example, I'm currently working with a target system that uses pointers with 6 bytes width.

Avoid at all costs to convert numbers in pointers or back.